# json format failing -->malformed JSON detected, please lint your request params

Tags: json

failing parsing JSON on a post call with malformed JSON

```
{

    "role": 

    {
        "name": "string2",
    },
    {
        "name": "string3",
    },
    {
        "name": "string4",
    },
}
```

Any help on formatting the json is really helpful

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I diagnose common errors in JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75188362/how-can-i-diagnose-common-errors-in-json-data)

Answer (score 1):

`role` should be a JSON array:

```
{
    "role": [
        {
            "name": "string2"
        },
        {
            "name": "string3"
        },
        {
            "name": "string4"
        }
    ]
}
```