# How can I diagnose common errors in JSON data?

Tags: python, json, debugging, syntax

I have to deal with putative JSON from a lot of different sources, and a lot of the time it seems that there is a problem with the data itself. I suspect that it sometimes isn't intended to be JSON at all; but a lot of the time it comes from a buggy tool, or it was written by hand for a quick test and has some typo in it.

Rather than ask about a specific error, I'm looking for a checklist: based on the error message, what is the most likely cause? What information is present in these error messages, and how can I use it to locate the problem in the data? Assume for these purposes that I can save the data to a temporary file for analysis, if it didn't already come from a file.

Comment: This is an artificial attempt at a canonical, which I have created because a lot of JSON questions seem to be motivated by some issue with the actual JSON data, rather than anything wrong in the actual code. Rather than close these as typos, it often seems more appropriate to provide guidance on *what* is wrong with the data, since it might not have been the OP's fault - for example, it could have been output by a buggy third-party tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Foreword

The only exception *explicitly* raised by [the decoding code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/json/decoder.py) is `json.JSONDecodeError`, so the exception type does not help diagnose problems. What's interesting is the associated message. However, it **is possible** that decoding bytes to text fails, before JSON decoding can be attempted. That is a separate issue beyond the scope of this post.

It's worth noting here that the JSON [format documentation](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) uses different terminology from Python. In particular, a portion of valid JSON data enclosed in `{}` is an *object* (not "dict") in JSON parlance, and a portion enclosed in `[]` is an *array* (not "list"). I will use JSON terminology when talking about the file contents, and Python terminology when talking about the parsed result or about data created directly by Python code.

As a general hint: use a dedicated JSON viewer to examine the file, or at least use a text editor that has some functionality to "balance" brackets (i.e., given that the insertion pointer is currently at a `{`, it will automatically find the matching `}`).

### Not JSON

An error message saying `Expecting value` is a strong indication that the data is not intended to be JSON formatted at all. Carefully note the line and column position of the error for more information:

- if the error occurs at [*line 1, column 1*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332), it will be necessary to inspect the beginning of the file. It could be that the data is actually **empty**. If it starts with `<`, then that of course suggests XML rather than JSON.
  Otherwise, there could be some padding preceding actual JSON content. Sometimes, this is [to implement a security restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690) in a web environment; in other cases it's to [work around a different restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472). The latter case is called JSONP (JSON with Padding). Either way, it will be necessary to inspect the data to figure out how much should be trimmed from the beginning (and possibly also the end) before parsing.
- other positions might be because the data is actually the `repr` of some native Python data structure. Data like this can often be parsed using `ast.literal_eval`, but it **should not be considered a practical serialization format** - it doesn't interoperate well with code not written in Python, and using `repr` can easily produce data that can't be recovered this way (or in *any* practical way).

Note some common differences between Python's native object representations and the JSON format, to help diagnose the problem:

- JSON uses **only** double quotes to surround strings; Python may also use single quotes, as well as triple-single (`'''example'''`) or triple-double (`"""example"""`) quotes.
- JSON uses lowercase `true` and `false` rather than `True` and `False` to represent booleans. It uses `null` rather than `None` as a special "there is nothing here" value. It uses `Infinity` and `NaN` to represent special floating-point values, rather than `inf` and `nan`.

One subtlety: `Expecting value` can also indicate a **trailing comma** in an array or object. JSON syntax does not allow a trailing comma after listing elements or key-value pairs, although Python does. Although the comma is "extra", this will be reported as something missing (the next element or key-value pair) rather than something extraneous (the comma).

---

An error message saying `Extra data` indicates that there is more text after the end of the JSON data.

- If the error occurs at **line 2 column 1**, this strongly suggests that the data is in fact in JSONL ("JSON Lines") format - a related format wherein each line of the input is a separate JSON entity (typically an object). Handling this is trivial: just iterate over lines of the input and parse each separately, and put the results in a list. For example, use a list comprehension: `[json.loads(line) for line in open_json_file]`. See [Loading JSONL file as JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475635) for more.
- Otherwise, the extra data could be part of JSONP padding. It can be removed before parsing; or else use the `.raw_decode` method of the `JSONDecoder` class:

  ```
  >>> import json
  >>> example = '{"key": "value"} extra'
  >>> json.loads(example) # breaks because of the extra data:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
      return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
      raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 18 (char 17)
  >>> parsed, size = json.JSONDecoder().raw_decode(example)
  >>> parsed
  {'key': 'value'}
  >>> size # amount of text that was parsed.
  16
  ```
- Another possibility - especially likely if the error is on **line 1**, at a low number for the column position (e.g. line 1, column 10), is that the data is **CSV** format. For example, this was the case in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75339096.

  This can happen because the value in the "top-left cell of the spreadsheet" represented by the CSV file contains a comma. When that happens, the CSV format needs to surround that string in quotes (so that comma isn't confused for a separator); that makes it look like valid JSON (for a JSON that only contains one string) followed by "extra data" (the comma separating that from the next "cell", along with the rest of the CSV data).

  For example, a valid CSV file could look like

  ```
  "x,y",z
  "(1, 2)",3
  ```

  The `"x,y"` is valid JSON by itself (representing exactly what one might expect), but parsing the whole thing causes an error:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
      return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
      raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)
  ```

### Invalid string literals

Error messages saying any of:

- `Invalid \\uXXXX escape`
- `Invalid \\escape`
- `Unterminated string starting at`
- `Invalid control character`

suggest that a string in the data isn't properly formatted, most likely due to a badly written escape code.

JSON strings can't contain control codes in strict mode (the default for parsing), so e.g. a newline must be encoded with `\n`. Note that the data must **actually contain a backslash**; when viewing a *representation of* the JSON data as a string, that backslash would then be doubled up (but not when, say, `print`ing the string).

JSON doesn't accept Python's `\x` or `\U` escapes, only `\u`. To represent characters outside the BMP, use a surrogate pair:

```
>>> json.loads('"\\ud808\\udf45"') # encodes Unicode code point 0x12345 as a surrogate pair
''
```

Unlike in Python string literals, a single backslash followed by something that doesn't make a valid escape sequence (such as a space) will **not** be accepted:

```
>>> json.loads('"\\ "') # the input string has only one backslash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Similarly, single-quotes **must not** be escaped within JSON strings, although double-quotes **must** be.

When debugging or testing an issue like this at the REPL, it's important not to get confused between JSON's escaping and Python's.

### Wrong brackets

`Expecting ',' delimiter` and `Expecting ':' delimiter` imply a mismatch between the brackets used for an object or array and the contents. For example, JSON like `["foo": "bar"]` was almost certainly intended to represent an object, so it should have enclosing `{}` rather than `[]`. Look at the line and character position where the error was reported, and then scan backwards to the enclosing bracket.

However, these errors can also mean exactly what they say: there might simply be a comma missing between array elements or key-value pairs, or a colon missing between a key and its value.

### Invalid key

While Python [allows anything hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257588) as a dict key, JSON requires strings for its object keys. This problem is indicated by `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`. While it could occur in hand-written JSON, it likely suggests the problem of data that was inappropriate created by using `repr` on a Python object. (This is especially likely if, upon checking the indicated location in the file, it appears that there is an attempt at a string key in **single** quotes.)

The error message `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes` could *also* indicate a "wrong brackets" problem. In particular, if the data should be an array that contains integers, but was enclosed in `{}` instead of `[]`, the parser would be expecting a double-quoted string key before anything else, and complain about the first integer in the list.